# how to match multiple times in one field in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

**This is the field**

```
device_version => 2.6.1.1280 [eng:v1.3.26.0 rul:v2018.07.12.09 act:v2018.01.20.01 sws:v2018.07.12.09]
```

How can I get eng, and rul ... value and put them individually to a new field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match `eng` and `rul` value, you can simple match them using `%{DATA}`,

```
eng:%{DATA:eng}\srul:%{DATA:rul}\s
```

This will output,

```
{
  "eng": [
    [
      "v1.3.26.0"
    ]
  ],
  "rul": [
    [
      "v2018.07.12.09"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can test it at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

**Edit:**

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "device_version" => "eng:%{DATA:eng}\srul:%{DATA:rul}\s" }
  }
}
```

You should also have a look at default grok patterns available, https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns

Comment: Thanks Sufiyan. I also want to put the value to a new field .. how can I do that ?

Comment: in the grok pattern `eng:%{DATA:eng}\srul:%{DATA:rul}\s` just change `eng` and `rul` to whatever name you want your field to be

Comment: mmm it gives me errors when I run logstash. _grokparsefailure

Comment: whats your actual log look like?

Comment: I added one filter by one filter to test, and it failed after I added the 4th one.   match => {"device_version" => "eng:%{DATA:engine}\srul:%{DATA:rule_database}\sact:%{DATA:action_database}\ssws:%{DATA:sws}\s"}

Comment: that's because there is no space character at the end of your log and `\s` matches space. this will work, `eng:%{DATA:engine}\srul:%{DATA:rule_database}\sact:%{DATA:action_database}\ssws:%{DATA:sws}`

Comment: one correction, the last part needs to be like this sws:%{DATA:sws}\ ], otherwise, it will not have the correct data.